# How to enable Gedit autosave files with name of current system Date and Time

Tags: 12.04, gedit

I want Gedit to autosave files, by the default name with the **current system Date and time**. Is this possible?

If not, is any hack to achieve the same?

The use of this feature is, the file names are unique by default and easy to find them for later.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a plugin available that will do the job.

- Download "doublesave.zip" from [here](https://code.google.com/p/double-save-gedit/downloads/list).
- Extract the contents and copy `doublesave.plugin` and `doublesave.py` to `~/.local/share/gedit/plugins`. If the folder does not exist, you will need to create it.
- Also create `~/gedit-backups` because the backup files will be stored here.
  Open gedit and enable the Doublesave plugin: select Edit  ▸ Preferences ▸ Plugins ▸ [Name of Plugin] to enable the plugin.

From now on, each time you save a file in gedit while working, a timestamped backup is created in `~/gedit-backups`.

---

It is also possible to tweak some things. For example, I've recently installed Dropbox and wanted to have `gedit-backups` in my Dropbox folder rather than in `~/home/user`. And I preferred my timestamp to be `%Y%m%d%H%M%S` rather than `%Y_%m_%d-%H_%M_%S`.

To make both those changes, edit `~/.local/share/gedit/plugins/doublesave.py`.

- create a folder called `gedit-backups` in the desired location
- open gedit, and untick the Doublesave plugin
- exit gedit
- delete  `~/.local/share/gedit/plugins/doublesave.pyc`
- edit  `~/.local/share/gedit/plugins/doublesave.py`

  - look for

    ```
    homedir = os.path.expanduser("~")+"/gedit-backups/"
    commands.getoutput("mkdir "+homedir)

    name = doc.get_short_name_for_display()

    timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%Y_%m_%d-%H_%M_%S")

    ext = ".bak"
    newFileName =  name+"-" + timestamp + ext
    newpath = "\""+homedir + newFileName+"\""
    command = "cp \""+source+"\" "+ newpath
    print command
    commands.getoutput(command)
    commands.getoutput("chmod -w "+newpath)
    ```
- change `homedir = os.path.expanduser("~")+"/gedit-backups/"` to what is required. I use `homedir = os.path.expanduser("~")+"/Dropbox/gedit-backups/"`
- change the timestamp as needed. I changed `"%Y_%m_%d-%H_%M_%S"` to `"%Y%m%d%H%M%S"`
- save the file
- reopen gedit and reinstall the Doublesave plugin.

Comment: @pajju, I edited the answer with a little more stuff.