# GTK scrollbar with transparent or no trough

Tags: themes, gtk, overlay-scrollbars, scrollbar

Is it possible in GTK-2 or/and GTK-3 to remove *the scrollbar trough* or make it invisible?

I know there are scripts to remove the scrollbar steppers, like:

```
GtkScrollbar::has-forward-stepper = 0
```

Now I want to know if there is such script to remove the trough.

In other words, GTK scrollbar is at the end of content, but I want to put it *over* the content – just like Overlay scrollbar.

**EDIT:** Let’s make my question more clear. I’ve edited both GTK-2 and GTK-3 themes to make scrollbars more similar to Overlay since I don’t like a low-contrast wide scrollbar. So I edited `gtkrc` and `gtk-widgets.css` files to change the slider color to orange and the trough to white, but as seen in the screenshot below the contrast between the trough and a dark background is annoying.

[image: gtk-2 white trough on a dark background]

**The question is here** if it’s possible to completely *remove* the trough or make it *transparent*. I guess the latter is possible.

My ideal is something like this:

[image: Terminal with Overlay scrollbar which has no trough]

Comment: I don't have an answer, but could you post your code for getting the GTK2 trough the color it is?  I've only managed to change the scroller itself.

Comment: @valadil yeah, it only supports `trough_shades` and `trough_border_shades` under `engine "murrign"`.

Answer (score 2):

Transparent colors (RGBA) are possible in **GTK-3** using `alpha`, so for making the trough transparent:

```
.scrollbar.trough,
.scrollbar.trough.vertical {
    border: alpha (@base_color, 0.0);
    background: alpha (@base_color, 0.0);
}
```

I don’t know about GTK-2 yet.

Comment: I came across [this](http://xubuntu.wordpress.com/2007/12/14/murrine-now-with-transparency/) by searching for "does murrine engine support transparency". BTW, I'll borrow your gtk3 code later in the day ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understood your question correctly but ...

I use Lubuntu 13.04 with the Greybird theme (`sudo apt-get install shimmer-themes`). I've heavily altered both the gtk2 and gtk3 aspects to suit my taste. The image shows a bit of a gedit  window (top) and a bit of my file manager, Thunar (below). As you can see, the trough is not really distinctive.

[image: scrollbar trough]

To get this effect, if that's what you're looking for, I edited `~/.themes/MyGreybird/gtk-2.0/gtkrc` and `~/.themes/MyGreybird/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` and `~/.themes/MyGreybird/gtk-3.0/gtk-widgets.css`.

Unfortunately, I really can't say whether it's this or that hack that gave me the current look. If you're looking for something like what I have, try editing the files similar to those I mentioned by looking for things like:

- `GtkScrollbar   ::trough-border`
- `prelight_shade` ... # shade level for scrollbar's slider, comboboxstyle(1), and prelight state with gradient_colors
- `trough_shades`     # draw gradient on trough of GtkScrollbar and GtkProgressbar

These are in `gtkrc` and I have commented them out in my theme by having `#` at the start of the line.

Then, in `gtk-widgets.css`, my theme has:

```
.scrollbars-junction,
.scrollbar.trough,
.scrollbar.trough.vertical {
    border-width: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
/*    background-image: -gtk-gradient(linear, left top, right top,
                                     from (shade(@theme_bg_color, 1.1)),
                                     to (shade(@theme_bg_color, 1.3)));*/
    background-color: shade(@theme_bg_color, 0.9);
}

.scrollbar.trough.horizontal {
/*    background-image: -gtk-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom,
                                     from (shade(@theme_bg_color, 1.1)),
                                     to (shade(@theme_bg_color, 1.3)));*/
    background-color: shade(@theme_bg_color, 0.9);
}
```

Again, I've commented out some stuff (using `/*` and `*/`).

I'm not sure I've made much sense but, basically, just look for relevant stuff and comment it out or modify it!

I use gedit as my editor [with a plug-in](https://askubuntu.com/a/308256/25656) that saves multiple, time-stamped backups so that if I break something, I can revert the changes.

*Please note that some applications may have their own scrollbar systems and you'll have to mess with those separately.*

Comment: Thanks for your time and the complete answer, but my question is about how to completely remove the trough, i.e. put the slider alone **on** the contents (not _beside_ them). I’ll edit my question to make it clear.